# read ArrayList elements

Tags: java, arraylist, println

Why it print the wrong output?

```
ArrayList<String> loc = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This arraylist stored the value of:

```
[topLeft, topLeft, topLeft, bottomLeft, topLeft, bottomLeft, topLeft, topLeft, Left, topLeft]
```

the firs index 0 is = topLeft

```
if(loc.get(1)=="topLeft")
   System.out.println("same")

else {
   System.out.println("not same")
}
```

This program print the wrong output `not same` instead of `same`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `equals(Object)` method, not the `==` operator, for example `loc.equals("topLeft")`

The `==` operator returns true if two references point to the same Object in memory. The [equals(Object o)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method checks whether the two objects are equivalent, so will return true if two Strings contain only the same characters in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

String comparison is done by calling `str1.equals(str2)` rather than using `==`.

- `equals(..)` compares the strings' contents
- `==` compares the references, and they are not the same.

There is a little more to know, however. `String` objects that are initialized as literals, i.e.

```
String str = "someString"
```

instead of via construction (`String str = new String("some")`) are all the same object. For them `==` would work.

And finally, for any `String`, calling `intern()` returns a `String` that is the same object as all other strings with the same content. (read `intern()`'s documentation for more info)

But the best practice here is to use `equals()`, while being careful if the object you are calling it on (the first string) is not `null`.